# php cli: using argv and getopt not working

Tags: php, command-line-interface, argv, getopt

Trying to use an argv variable and getopt() doesn't seem to work.  Anyone know of a work around other than using all - or -- options:

```
<?php
$arr[] = "test:";
$options = getopt(NULL, $arr);
echo $options["test"];
?>
```

Simple example above, when I run:

```
php test.php --test="Hello World"
```

Hello World

```
php test.php argv --test="Hello World"
```

No output, because I placed a value without a - or -- before it.

Comment: http://php.net/getopt - *"The parsing of options will end at the first non-option found, anything that follows is discarded."*

Comment: Yes, I do notice now that it says: "The parsing of options will end at the first non-option found, anything that follows is discarded."  Seems pretty inconvenient.  Still looking forward to a workaround.

Comment: Yes looks a bit short-sighted. Especially as the input to the function can not be provided.

Comment: Try to use `$_SERVER['argv']`

Comment: If your first parameter is always going to be a command, you can remove it from the $argv array after processing it. For example: $command = $argv[1]; array_shift( $argv );

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_opt() {
    $options = array();
    foreach( $_SERVER[ "argv" ] as $key => $arg ) {
        if ( preg_match( '@\-\-(.+)=(.+)@', $arg, $matches ) ) {
            $key   = $matches[ 1 ];
            $value = $matches[ 2 ];
            $options[ $key ] = $value;
        } else if ( preg_match( "@\-(.)(.)@", $arg, $matches ) ) {
            $key   = $matches[ 1 ];
            $value = $matches[ 2 ];
            $options[ $key ] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Even if your answer might be correct, adding a little explaination won't harm anyone and will encourage other users to upvote your answers.

Comment: Your code does work for my example, I'll give you that, but it doesn't work for real usage.  I made my own work around, I'll post it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little brute-force, but it solves my related problem better. Based on user3307546's answer:

```
function get_opts() {
    $opts = array();
    foreach($_SERVER["argv"] as $k => $a){
        if(preg_match( '@\-\-(.+)=(.+)@'  , $a, $m))
            $opts[$m[1]] = $m[2];
        elseif(preg_match( '@\-\-(.+)@'   , $a, $m))
            $opts[$m[1]] = true;
        elseif(preg_match( '@\-(.+)=(.+)@', $a, $m))
            $opts[$m[1]] = $m[2];
        elseif(preg_match( '@\-(.+)@'     , $a, $m))
            $opts[$m[1]] = true;
        else
            $opts[$k] = $a;
    }
    return $opts;
}
```

So

```
> php cli/index.php gen/cache/reports -e --refresh-api -s="2020-04-16" -v
```

Is parsed as

```
{
    0: "cli/index.php",
    1: "ttd/cache/reports",
    "e": true,
    "refresh-api": true,
    "s": "2020-04-16",
    "v": true
}
```

All "non-options" appear with their ordinal position in the hash key.